# Mounting Error at Boot

Tags: 11.04, boot, fstab

So recently I've been having a strange issue where Ubuntu kicks back an error stating there was an "Error mounting "0" " and to press S to skip.

This is what my fstab looks like. Can anyone tell me exactly which lines/entries should be erased without doing any harm so it no longer attempts to mount "0"? 
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first line under the "proc" mount, where you are mounting `/host` has something wrong with it.  If you notice, the portion that reads `defaults,nls=utf8,umask=0222,nosuid,nodev` is repeated on the next line.  I can't tell from the screen grab if that is truly a separate line or not, but it probably shouldn't be there twice either way.
It should read: `/dev/sda2  /host  ntfs   defaults,nls=utf8,umask=0222,nosuid,nodev   0   0`
I use tabs for the whitespace, but any whitespace will do.